# Is there a limit of how many IP addresses can be in sourceRanges in a single project firewall rule?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have found out there is a limit of 500(?) rules per project.

But how many IP addresses can be present within sourceRanges, for a single rule?

According to the firewall API documentation, the field is a JSON string.

https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/firewalls

```
  "sourceRanges": [
    string
  ],
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit for source IP ranges field is 256 for a single rule. This means you can add up to 256 IP ranges.

Comment: I searched the documentation for this value. Do you have a document link for this value? If not, we should improve the documentation on this page: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/quota under `Firewall rules`.

Comment: Just to be clear @ilia-borovoi, that is a limit of 256 comma separated ip addresses can be in sourceranges?

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't look like this limit is written in any GCP articles. I've sent a document update request to add this limit to the list.

Mathnode, correct, this limit is for unique IP ranges in the source range separated by comma.

Answer (score 1):

Creating firewall rule failed. Error: Value for field 'resource.sourceRanges' is too large: maximum size 5000 element(s)

Limited to 5000 IP address rages with CIDR.